# Azure Data Factory Datasets - HTTP Datastore is missing

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have noticed that, currently HTTP as a data source is not available in Azure Data Factory. This was available as an option until a couple of days ago. I can't see any changes to the documentation to reflect this either. Does anyone know whether this is intentionally removed. Please see below for a screenshot of what I am talking about.

Note - I can still see this as an integration dataset under Synapse. So, it seem to be removed just from ADF.

[image: Screenshot of Datastores]

Comment: yes, this can be a bug. I am also facing the same issue. I have raised the bug request [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/issues/644) please check for upcoming updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems as intermittent issue. I just tried to create ADF in `central india` and `north europe` regions and tried same. I am able to see HTTP connector now. Check below screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @ShaikMaheer, I still can't see the HTTP datasource, my ADF is in UK South region. Could you please take a look. Thanks

Comment: It works now! I assume there was a fix applied to the product!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can agree that the http connector is no longer available in ADF and there are similar threads :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1524337/azure-data-factory-datasets-http-datastore-is-miss?orderby=helpful#answers

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1524104/http-dataset-is-not-available-in-datasets-store?page=1&orderby=Helpful#answers

Might be some recent deployment issue creating this bug.

Would reach out to internal team and confirm on the same.